# Which use of Linq Any() is more efficient?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query which looks as follows:

```
return this._alarmObjectAlarmViolationList
   .Where(row => row.ObjectId == subId)
   .Where(row => row.AlarmInternalId == "WECO #1 (StdDev > UCL)")
   .Where(row => row.PositionInSequence == row.SequenceCount)
   .Any();
```

Is this functionaly any different, or any more or less efficient, than putting the Where predicates inside the Any() statement?

This is a Linq to Objects query.

Thank you.

Comment: Which kind of linq is this? linq-to-objects, or one of the `IQueryable` based variants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no real difference in execution speed between `.Where(predicate).Any()` and `Any(predicate)`.

However, using only `Any(predicate)` internally requires less objects to be created.

My suggestion is that you use the variant that is more readable. With many complicated predicates, I think it is easier to read when you use `Where` - as in your sample.

Please note: My answer only applies to LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Thank you. This is Linq to Objects.